# Purpose of extra pin slots on Pololu DRV8835

Tags: pins

I have a Pololu DRV8835 motor controller. I managed to properly solder and connect it and it actually works, however I've been wondering about the purpose of the extra pin slots - especially the ones without pins headers soldered to them on the right side of the picture below, but also the ones marked A and B (I assume these ones are an alternative way to connect to motors, though). I wasn't able to find anything about them, so I assumed that it may be obvious to someone who is not a complete beginner (like me). What, if anything, could I use them for if I soldered pin headers there?
[image: Pololu DRV8835 mounted on an Arduino]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A and B are the same as the A and B screw terminals.

The pins on the right, if you use your eyes and follow the traces, are the same as the pins that plug into the Arduino. I guess they are intended to be used to isolate the existing pin assignments (cut tracks on the underside between adjacent holes with a knife) and solder wires to other pins so you aren't limited to just using the pins they have assigned.

Comment: Thanks! What about the five pins next to the five you explained (the ones separated by white lines)?

Comment: They are all the same. Turn the board over and look at the traces. You can see they are joined. You can cut those traces that join them if you want to wire it to other pins on the Arduino instead, then when you want to undo it you can solder a wire between the holes to replace the track you cut.

Comment: The A and B through-holes are intended to let you connect the two motor channels together in parallel (M1A to M2A and M1B and M2B) to drive a single higher-current motor. See the section "Configuring the board for single-channel mode (parallel outputs)" on the product page (https://www.pololu.com/product/2511); there is a lot of other usage information there too.